# How to break a line in a long equation?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am using a class named `abntex2` and I don't know how to break an equation.
I've tried inserting a package `amsmath`, `breqn`, `mathtools`, but it does not work.

I type:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

...

and when I insert the equation, I write:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
\left({{\varphi}^{x}{\frac{\partial}{{\partial}u_{x}}}+{\varphi}^{t}{\frac{\partial}{{\partial}u_{t}}} \\
+{\varphi}^{xx}{\frac{\partial}{{\partial}u_{xx}}}+{\varphi}^{xt}{\frac{\partial}{{\partial}u_{xt}}} \\
+{\varphi}^{tt}{\frac{\partial}{{\partial}u_{tt}}}+{\varphi}^{xxx}{\frac{\partial}{{\partial}u_{xxx}}}}\right){\left(u_{t}+u_{xxx}+mu^{m-1}u_{x}\right)} \\
={\varphi}^{x}{\left({mu^{m-1}}\right)}+{\varphi}^{t}+{\varphi}^{xxx}
\end{equation}
\end{multlined}
```

But the double bar does not work. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Use `multline`. Sorry for abnt rules.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Yes, Sigur, but i've used {multline} too.

Comment: Please post a **complete** Minimal (non-)Working Example. Much more useful than code fragments.

Comment: it wouldn't solve all problems, but if `\begin{equation}` comes before `\begin{xxx}`, then `\end{equation` has to come *after* `\end{xxx}`.  proper nesting is a must.

Answer (score 4):

You have mixed up the `equation` and `multiline` environments. Also it is `multline` not `multlined`. Further, I have removed many braces that seemed un-necessary. You have used many of them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%\begin{equation}
\begin{multline}
\biggl(\varphi^{x}{\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{x}}}+\varphi^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{t}}
+\varphi^{xx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xx}}+\varphi^{xt}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xt}} \\
+\varphi^{tt}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{tt}}+\varphi^{xxx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xxx}}\biggr)\left(u_{t}+u_{xxx}+mu^{m-1}u_{x}\right) \\
=\varphi^{x}{\left(mu^{m-1}\right)}+\varphi^{t}+\varphi^{xxx}
%\end{equation}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also note that you can't use `\left(` and `\right)` across lines. I have used `biggl(` and `\biggr)` which do not have this constraint. For details, please refer to `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsldoc` from command prompt)

To use `\left(` and `\right)` across lines you have to use the placeholders `\right.` and `left.`, see how here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%\begin{equation}
\begin{multline}
\left(\varphi^{x}{\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{x}}}+\varphi^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{t}}
+\varphi^{xx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xx}}+\varphi^{xt}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xt}} \right. \\
\left. +\varphi^{tt}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{tt}}+\varphi^{xxx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xxx}}\right)\left(u_{t}+u_{xxx}+mu^{m-1}u_{x}\right) \\
=\varphi^{x}{\left(mu^{m-1}\right)}+\varphi^{t}+\varphi^{xxx}
%\end{equation}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

note the `\right. \\` at the end of the first line and `\left.` at the beginning of the second.
The visual outcome is the same as above.

Another option using `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\biggl(\varphi^{x}{\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{x}}}+\varphi^{t}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{t}}
+\varphi^{xx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xx}}+\varphi^{xt}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xt}} \\
& \quad+\varphi^{tt}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{tt}}+\varphi^{xxx}\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{xxx}}\biggr)\left(u_{t}+u_{xxx}+mu^{m-1}u_{x}\right) \\
&\qquad \quad {}={}\varphi^{x}{\left(mu^{m-1}\right)}+\varphi^{t}+\varphi^{xxx}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the solution to `\left(` and `\right)` across lines is to use the phantom placeholders `\right.` and `\left.` respectively at the end and the beginning of the line

Comment: @Federico `\left` and `\right` is to be used very judiciously as it is not needed most of the times. `\bigl` and brothers are sufficient in most of the cases. :)

Answer (score 2):

Some slight change to ease the typing of the equation given in Harish Kumar's answer. Use the commath package to typeset the derivatives easily.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,commath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\biggl(\varphi^{x}\dpd{}{u_{x}}+
  \varphi^{t}\dpd{}{u_{t}}
  +\varphi^{xx}\dpd{}{u_{xx}}+\varphi^{xt}\dpd{}{u_{xt}} \\
& \quad+\varphi^{tt}\dpd{}{u_{tt}}+\varphi^{xxx}\dpd{}{u_{xxx}}
  \biggr)\left(u_{t}+u_{xxx}+mu^{m-1}u_{x}\right) \\
& \qquad \quad {}={}\varphi^{x}{\left(mu^{m-1}\right)}+
  \varphi^{t}+\varphi^{xxx}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]